# WhatsApp Web in Fluid throws JavaScript exception

Tags: javascript, web-app, fluid.app

When I'm starting the WhatsApp web client in a Fluid app, this JavaScript exception is thrown:

```
[Error] TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'e.getDatabaseNames')
    U (app_59f797fae4fc761b3ee8.js, line 63)
    c (app_59f797fae4fc761b3ee8.js, line 62)
    n (app_59f797fae4fc761b3ee8.js, line 6)
    (anonymous function) (app_59f797fae4fc761b3ee8.js, line 6)
    t (app_59f797fae4fc761b3ee8.js, line 5)
    (anonymous function) (app_59f797fae4fc761b3ee8.js, line 5)
    t (app_59f797fae4fc761b3ee8.js, line 5)
    (anonymous function) (app_59f797fae4fc761b3ee8.js, line 5)
    webpackJsonp (app_59f797fae4fc761b3ee8.js, line 5)
    global code (crypto_8cbbef38a0cf6ff138dc.js, line 2)
```

This leads an infinite loading screen.

When I launch WhatsApp Web in Safari `e` is a `IDBFactory`, but it looks like the IndexedDB API isn't available in a Fluid app (there `e` is null).

You have to set either Firefox, Chrome or Safari as user agent to get to the loading screen. I tried playing around with the settings, but nothing seems to help.

I wrote a mail to the FluidApp support, but no answer so far. Does anyone have advice?

Comment: I'm running into just the same problem; unfortunately I don't have any solution. I also have emailed the developer of Fluid, but no response.

Comment: I really hope Fluid does not become abandonware. But the latest twit on fluid twitter is 3 years old. I don't have high hopes that solution would be available.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a solution that works with Fluid, but [Aluxian/WhatsApp-Desktop](https://github.com/Aluxian/WhatsApp-Desktop) on GitHub provides an open-source wrapper for the WhatsApp web app which works well and provides similar functionality to what Fluid would.

Comment: One of the main reasons for using FluidApp is to get long lasting battery and use the internal webkit version. The open source suggestion is based on NW.js which uses V8 and Chrome internals, which defeats the purpose for so many Fluid users.

Answer (score 1):

Stumbled upon the same, but I found a very good wrapper for whatsapp that feels very well integrated with OSX look&feel: [ChitChat](https://github.com/stonesam92/ChitChat). It being OSS is a great plus for me.

Comment: This is very good. I wish all vendors had this approach, much like the one for facebook. https://fbmacmessenger.rsms.me -- which is also open source.

Answer (score -1):

Use this , very simple and elegant -

https://github.com/stonesam92/ChitChat

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone.